# Change Background Of Button In Unityscript

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I can't seem to convert this C# code to javascript (unityscript) here it is:

```
public Color buttonColor;
GetComponent<Image>().color = buttonColor;
```

This is what I've Tried:

```
var buttonColor : Color;
GetComponent(Image).color = buttonColor;
```

Like other questions I'm not trying to get an object of colors. I want one Color variable and change the color of a button using that variable.

My Error Is: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
iPhone Investment.Update () (at Assets/__Scripts/iPhone Investment.js:29)

Another error I'm getting is: Unkown identifier: Image

Comment: Does it work? Do you get any error? You just posted a script without describing your problem

Comment: @Programmer I get an error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Is this just a typo or something else? You have `GetComponemt` instead of `GetComponent` for Javascrpt...

Comment: @Programmer Sorry it was just a typo in my question.

Comment: Check my answer. To be honest, you should be using C# with Unity but you go whatever you want.

Comment: I'm fluent in both languages only since I've been a web developer for some time unityscript is more familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NullReferenceException` error, that's because using `GetComponent` will only get Component on the GameObject the script is attached to. That line of code is failing because the script is **not** attached to a **GameObject** with an `Image` component.

Either attach the script to a GameObject with an `Image` Component or Find that GameObject with the Image component first then perform `GetComponent` on it.

```
GameObject.Find("MyImageName").GetComponent(Image).color = buttonColor;
```

Finally, Unity automatically assign `0` to the alpha value of `Color` variable declared in script. Make sure to change `alpha` variable  of the `buttonColor` from the Editor to `1` or else the image will disappear when you click Play

**EDIT**:

For your new error, you must add `import UnityEngine.UI;` to the top of your script. Since you mentioned that this is done in the `Update` function, you must do the `GameObject.Find` outside the Update function to cache the `Image` component for later use.

```
import UnityEngine.UI;

private var myImage:Image;
public var buttonColor : Color;

function Start () {
    myImage = GameObject.Find("MyImageName").GetComponent(Image);
}

function Update () {
    myImage.color = buttonColor;
}
```

If you want to change other button color properties such as `pressedColor`,`highlightedColor` and `disabledColor`, you do it like below:

```
import UnityEngine.UI;

private var myButton:Button;
public var buttonColor : Color;

function Start () {
    //myButton = GameObject.Find("MyButtonName").GetComponent(Button);
    myButton = GameObject.Find("Button").GetComponent(Button);
}

function Update () {

    var colorBlock = myButton.colors;
    colorBlock.normalColor = new Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    colorBlock.highlightedColor = new Color(0, 1, 0.0, 1.0);
    colorBlock.disabledColor = new Color(0, 0, 1, 1.0);

    myButton.colors = colorBlock;
}
```

Comment: My Code (Except for the variable) is in the update function.

Comment: And I'm trying to change the background of a button. Will your answer still work or help>

Comment: Also the script is attached to a button.

Comment: Could you go `GameObject.Find(this)`?

Comment: No. Please look the example I provided in my answer. You provide the nameof the GameObject it. As for your new error you must have `import UnityEngine.UI;` at the top of your script.

Comment: Check my new Edit which reflects the things you mentioned in the comments. Happy coding!